# pointer state by address

Tags: c++, windows, access-violation

I've got an access violation in my program. I know Windows decodes some states in the address of a pointer (e.g. `0xcccccccc` or `0xcdcdcdcd` for uninitialized or freed memory, iirc). I couldn't find any docs covering those decodings, a link to them would be much appreciated.

For now I'm specifically looking for the meaning (if any) behind `0x000000000000007F` (64bit process).

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph of your post, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: `0x000000000000007F` looks like you tried to read something from a `nullptr`.

Comment: actually I doubt that `0x000000000000007F` is a placeholder. Usually bit patterns are chosen that are easy to spot and that are unlikely to appear otherwise, eg `0xDEADBEEF` or the like

Comment: @churill oof that would be bad, there is some dynamic marshalling involved on the error side -.-

Comment: `0x000000000000007F` does not have any special meaning. Most likely it's a dereferencement of a structure member such as `Foo->bar = 42`, where `Foo` is NULL. But without seeing any code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

0x000000000000007F is not any debug bit pattern to my knowledge. I can think of a few likely meanings for the value:

- It happens to be the largest value representable by signed 8 bit number.
- It happens to consist of a sequence of zeroes, then a sequence of 1. This is quite typical with bitmasks.
- In ASCII it is the "Delete" character.
- It is fairly small number, and therefore quite likely to have meaning for the numerical value.

Comment: Interesting. I've fixed the code causing that error by now, but now it appears on a different location :/. It's related to managed unmanaged marshalling but I haven't figured it out yet.